# Nicer syntax when combining Future[Option[_]] with plain Future[_] using OptionT

Tags: scala

Assuming I have `f(a: Int): Future[Option[T]]` and `g(b: Int): Future[K]`, I can combine them like follows with cats's `OptionT`:

```
for {
  f <- OptionT(f(a))
  g <- OptionT(g(b).map(Option.apply)
} yield (f, g)
```

Is there nicer way to do this without mapping over each `Future[_]`?

Comment: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html#from-optiona-andor-fa-to-optiontf-a

Comment: @prayagupd, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a small improvement would be to do something like:

```
for {
  f <- OptionT(f(a))
  g <- OptionT.liftF(g(b))
} yield (f, g)
```